# Recharts tooltip with pointer (react,tooltip)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, line, recharts

On a line graph trying to display tooltip with pointer  that shows dashed lines going to x-axis and y-axis accordingly. The problem is I can use them separately but not together because onMouseMove state interferes with the display of the tooltip. Is there a solution for this?[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some of your code.

Comment: Hi Adam, tried a few routes including taking the margin out the class:  const  margin = { top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 0, right: 50 };
class Chart extends Component {                                                     and then inside the class:                                                  <ResponsiveContainer aspect={3} width='100%'    > 
 <LineChart data={data} margin={margin}

Comment: Also tried to play with the css such as :                                                            .customizedTooltip{
pointer-events: none;
position:absolute;
display:block;
opacity:1;
width:100%;
placement: bottom;
opacity:0.7;
z-index:1000000;
visibility:visible;


}


.wrapper {


  position: relative;
  pointer-events:auto;
  opacity:0.5;
  visibility:visible;






}

Comment: What really seemed to do the job was in the console(F12,inspect) to change visibility:visible!important for the recharts-tooltip-wrapper but than the tooltip stays after hover is over. In addition, was not able to reach this in the code

Comment: The code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262653/recharts-tooltip-with-pointer-react-tooltip-code-part.                                                                               With the css showed in the code sometimes it seemed that the tooltip co-exists with the x/y-axis dashed lines but sometimes couldn't see neither the tooltip nor the dashed lines and sometimes only the lines